Difference b/w "from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma" and "from langchain_chroma import Chroma"
There are two ways to import "Chroma" from langchain as below.
https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain_community.vectorstores.chroma.Chroma.html
and
https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/vectorstores/langchain_chroma.vectorstores.Chroma.html#langchain_chroma.vectorstores.Chroma
Methods in both sites are completely the same. I have already used langchain_community for embedding, so I do not want to install extra packages such as "langchain_chroma".
I have two questions.

Why there are two ways?
Which one should I use?

Please enlighten me.

Probably based simply on how you plan to use langchain. You dont need langchain_chroma installed as well. I have pip install chromadb and langchain_community uses it with from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma. I got there by following this tute (though check comments for the things he forgot to say need installing). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jENqvjpkwmw
